# What archive format to exchange data from Linux to a Mac?

Tags: macos, zip, archiving

I need to give a friend who has a Mac a bunch of files. Compression doesn't matter, only ease of use. What archive format do you recommend such that no 3rd party tools are needed for extraction? Zip?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gzipped Tarball. Should work anywhere.

---

Compress:

```
tar czvf my-files.tar.gz directory-of-files
```

(or right-click and "Compress", "Archive" on many distros)

---

Extract:

```
tar xcvf my-files.tar.gz .
```

(or double-click on a Mac)

Comment: That's great. Please consider marking your question as answered so it doesn't stay open!

Answer (score 1):

[Archive Utility](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archive_Utility), which is part of Mac OS X, supports tons of formats for extraction, among these: `zip`, `gzip` and `bzip2`.